# Conversion tag written in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am researching the following conversion tag written in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag_id = 123456789;
var adnetwork_domain = "https://s.adnetwork.net";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s2.adnetwork.net/js/adnetworkRt.js"></script>
```

**https://s2.adnetwork.net/js/adnetworkRt.js**

```
if ("undefined" == typeof adnetwork_domain) var adnetwork_domain = "https://s.adnetwork.net";
if ("undefined" == typeof adnetworkRt) var adnetworkRt = {
    init: function() {
        try {
            if (-1 != document.cookie.indexOf("adnetworkoptout")) return 0;
            "undefined" != typeof tag_id && document.createElement("img").setAttribute("src", adnetwork_domain + "/rt.php?tag_id=" + tag_id)
        } catch (a) {
            console.log(a)
        }
    }
};
var adnetwork_user_agent = navigator.userAgent;
!navigator.cookieEnabled || (-1 == adnetwork_user_agent.search(/AppleWebKit/) || -1 == adnetwork_user_agent.search(/Android/) && -1 == adnetwork_user_agent.search(/iPhone/) && -1 == adnetwork_user_agent.search(/iPod/) && -1 == adnetwork_user_agent.search(/iPad/)) || adnetworkRt.init();
```

In the following part, I cannot understand the reason of making img tag and where the img tag is set.

```
document.createElement("img").setAttribute("src", adnetwork_domain + "/rt.php?tag_id=" + tag_id)
```

Could you tell me the answer?

Comment: If you set the `src` attribute of an image (`document.createElement("img")` or `new Image()`) the browser will fetch the resource by sending a GET request. For this to happen you don't have to add the image to the DOM ([web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon)) Tl;dr: the line quoted sends a GET request with the `tag_id` as parameter to the ad network.

Comment: Thank you! I understand!

Comment: @Andreas, could you extend on your comment and add it as an answer to this question so that it may be closed by @supermonkey? Thanks!